# Return True Or False In SQL With My Combo Box Selected Value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows, ado.net

I am Using ADO.NET To Make Application.
I Have a Combo Box With Collection List Of 2 Values as:

1) Active

2) Inactive

When I Select Active It Should Return **True**
and When I Select Inactive It Should Return **False** To My Database Column Whose Type Is Bit.
But It Returns Null.

My Code Is:

```
DatabaseEntities DB = new DatabaseEntities;
TableName tblObject = new TableName();

If(ComboBox.SelectedText == "Active")
{
    tblObject.StatusColumnInSql = true;
}

else
{
    tblObject.StatusColumnInSql = false;
}
```

BUT ITS NOT WORKING

Comment: Did you use debugger to go through the codes?

Comment: Yes I Did but its getting null value

Comment: _It's not working_ is the most useless phrase you could say when searching for help. What is not working? What is the value of SelectedText at the point of your test? Put a breakpoint and check the value.

Comment: I Checked It Returns Empty Quotes. "" Like This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ComboBox.SelectedValue`.

Example:

```
 tblObject.StatusColumnInSql = (ComboBox.SelectedValue == 0);
```